# Ubuntu 20.04 lost GUI after updating

Tags: boot

After I installed and update some packages (sdl2-dev) in Ubuntu 20.04, some stuff disappeared (wifi icon in Settings, internet connection, Settings not opening). Now it boots into console mode and after pressing the arrow keys (left, up, right..) prints this error message, but I can login and run commands.

[image]

Comment: I would take the educated guess that this set of video apps has wiped out your GUI interface. You may want to edit your title Ubuntu seems to boot fine it is only the GUI.

Comment: I dont know how call such error

Comment: Ubuntu lost GUI after installing sdl2-dev

Comment: Are you able to reinstall missing packages with `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`? (the caret "^" on the end is important). It should put back the default packages.

Comment: Ok, I will try it little bit later

Comment: popey: I check, I have no internet (ethernet) connection, and `sudo apt update` fails. Aslo can't up connection with `sudo ip link set eno1 up`. Other net utils dissapeared.

Comment: My keyboard have long delay (i need to press key 1-2 sec, if I want print something)

Comment: Ok, I solved everything. First I enter recovery mode using grub. Second I connected to internet via cable, and follow steps in this guide (using ip command) https://serverfault.com/questions/21475/starting-network-connection-from-ubuntu-recovery/975941#975941?newreg=f04260cceb8646948a4347b63c419cf7 Then I write `sudo apt update` `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` and fix every missing and broken package by myself. That's it